# Job search with Careers 2.0?

Tags: discussion, jobs

Has anyone gotten calls from potential employers from their Careers 2.0 profile?

Comment: Discussing other job websites is off topic.  Hell, this might still be closed as not constructive, but I think asking the effectiveness of the Careers site may be ok.

Comment: I've received more than I've responded to, that's for sure.  My current job was found through SO Careers, though.  But they didn't find me, I found them.

Comment: I think this is a (bad) poll; that said, I haven't even been contacted.  I haven't put much work into my profile, though my LinkedIn is about the same and there I get contacted a few times a month.

Comment: I've gotten a fair amount of offers.  In fact, have one possible hire in the works right now.

Answer (score 8):

Yes.

That is, I've now been hired twice through connections I have made on SO careers. The latest time, the employer looked me up and had printouts of my profile and answers. The first time, I found them through a search and then they looked at my profile.

Comment: I'd like to talk to you about your experiences.  May I contact you at your SO account email address?

Comment: @NickLarsen by all means!

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
Thanks to my help in a SO tag, a company who was looking an employee for technology of the tag  contacted with me.